# How to import json into mongo using docker-compose?

Tags: json, mongodb, docker

I'm trying to start a docker container with mongodb image and import a default json set.
I've seen a lot of people recommend --host flag but it doesn't seem to help.

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        image: mongo:3.4.1
        build: db
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
```

and dockerfile

```
FROM mongo
WORKDIR /usr/src/db
COPY init.json .
RUN mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log
RUN mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1 --db test --collection users /usr/src/db/init.json
```

but I get the usual message

```
Step 5/5 : RUN mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1 --db test --collection users /usr/src/db/init.json
---> Running in f953a6fd5331
2018-01-17T23:16:54.854+0000    Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1 --db test --collection users /usr/src/db/init.json' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I tried IP addresses 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, the container name "db", with/without starting daemon, runing commands in various orders between docker-compose and dockerfile but nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much digging around I found the answer, and why.
As suggested docker starts a container, runs the command and closes the container. Data doesn't persist so you can create the default set but it gets lost on the next line of the dockerfile.

The Answer was to to create the set when mongo starts.

DockerFile

```
FROM mongo
WORKDIR /usr/src/data
COPY data.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

data.js

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('mycollection');

db.foo.insert({
    "key": "value"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start the database and the init shell in the same docker layer:

```
RUN mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log &&\
 mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1 --db test --collection users /usr/src/db/init.json
```